# Object of generic functions

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get this typescript to work, but I can't work out how to type the `openPromises` object to have the `resolve` function not have an error because it's mistyped. The error I am seeing is:

```
Type '(value?: B | PromiseLike<B> | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '<C>(value?: C | undefined) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'C | undefined' is not assignable to type 'B | PromiseLike<B> | undefined'.
            Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'B | PromiseLike<B> | undefined'.
                Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<B>'.
```

An easy workaround to this is to type the value of `openPromises` as `any`, but was hoping to improve on that and learn a bit more about complex generic types in the process.

Here is the code I have that demonstrates my issue. My source is much more complex, but this is the minimum I could create that demonstrates the issue

```
interface DefaultResponse {
    a: 'a'
}

const openPromises: {
    [id: string]: { resolve<C>(value?: C): void }
} = {};

function putInObject<B extends DefaultResponse>(id: string) {
    return new Promise<B>(resolve => {
        openPromises[id] = { resolve }; 
    }) 
}

// ----------

interface MyResponse1 extends DefaultResponse {
    AA: string;
}

putInObject<MyResponse1>("test1").then(console.log);

const response1: MyResponse1 = { a:'a', AA: "test" };
openPromises["test1"].resolve(response1)


interface MyResponse2 extends DefaultResponse {
    BB: string;
}

putInObject<MyResponse2>("test2").then(console.log);

const response2: MyResponse2 = { a:'a', BB: "test" };
openPromises["test2"].resolve(response2)
```

You can see the error in the left side of [this typescript code sandbox](https://agentcooper.github.io/typescript-play/#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). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that what you are trying to do is not really type safe. A generic function is one that has the type argument decided by the caller. In your case, the caller can only pass in a single type that is valid, the type that was decided when `putInObject` was called for a particular id. So for example this is allowed, even though it's not valid:

```
putInObject<MyResponse1>("test1").then(r => console.log(r.AA)); // expecting r to be MyResponse1
openPromises["test1"].resolve({ a:'a', BB: "test" }) // I can pas in anything since resolve is generic
```

There  isn't a good way to type `openPromises` upfront that is truly type safe. Since there is only one valid type for each key and the keys are added later we can't really use a type for `openPromise` what will emulate this behavior.

There are two workarounds I can think of.

### Mutating the type of the original object

Typescript does not allow us to change the type of a variable after it has been declared, we cold however return from `putInObject`, the same object but with a different type and subsequently use this new object instead. Below, I used a class to keep the current type of `openPromisses`

```
class OpenPromisesManager<T = {}> {
  readonly openPromises: T = {} as T;
  putInObject<B extends DefaultResponse>(){
    return <TKey extends string>(id: TKey, withPromise: (p:Promise<B>) => void): OpenPromisesManager<T & Record<TKey, { resolve(value?: B): void }>> =>  {
      const newThis = this as any ;
      withPromise(new Promise<B>(resolve => {
          newThis.openPromises[id] = { resolve }; 
      }));
      return newThis as OpenPromisesManager<T & Record<TKey, { resolve(value?: B): void }>>;
    }
  }
}

// ----------

interface MyResponse1 extends DefaultResponse {
  AA: string;
}
const mgr = new OpenPromisesManager()
const mgr2 = mgr.putInObject<MyResponse1>()("test1", p=> p.then(r=> console.log(r.AA)));

const response1: MyResponse1 = { a:'a', AA: "test" };
mgr2.openPromises["test1"].resolve(response1)
mgr2.openPromises["test1"].resolve({ a:'a', BB: "test" }) // error
```

### Using a key that captures the request type

Another option is to have a key that keeps  in its type the expected return type of the promise. This allows us to create a `get`function that will return an object with the apropriate `resolve` type.

```
const openPromises: unknown = {};

type Key<T> = string & { __type: T }
function key<T>(k: string) {
  return k as Key<T>;
}
function putInObject<B extends DefaultResponse>(id: Key<B>) {
  return new Promise<B>(resolve => {
    (openPromises as any)[id] = { resolve }; 
  }) 
}

function get<B>(id: Key<B>): { resolve(value?: B): void } {
  return (openPromises as any)[id];
}

// ----------

interface MyResponse1 extends DefaultResponse {
  AA: string;
}

const test1 = key<MyResponse1>("test1");
putInObject<MyResponse1>(test1).then(console.log);

const response1: MyResponse1 = { a:'a', AA: "test" };
get(test1).resolve(response1)
get(test1).resolve({ a: 'a', BB: ''}) // error
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks for the help!